# Does PDF/A-3b requires PDF V1.7 or PDF V1.4?

Tags: pdfx

I'm using the `pdfx` package to generate PDF/A. I'm  using as well the `embedfile` package to attach file to the PDF/A-3b.

Now my question is: Does PDF/A-3b requires PDF V1.7 or PDF V1.4?

```
\usepackage[a-3b,pdf17]{pdfx}
```

or

```
\usepackage[a-3b]{pdfx}
```

Comment: Wrong forum. That is unrelated to TeX. It is about PDF/A standards. Search the Internet for info. Whether you need 1.7 or can simply use 1.4 is a matter of document content. For arbitrary file attachment you probably need 1.7.